# Почему raycast смещается при вращении фигуры?

Tags: unity3d

Почему raycast смещается при вращении фигуры?

По началу всё нормально, а когда фигура вращается, то лучи смещают в разные стороны, а потом опять возвращаются на исходные позиции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 RaycastHit raycastHitFront = new RaycastHit();
 RaycastHit raycastHitLeft = new RaycastHit();
 RaycastHit raycastHitRight = new RaycastHit();

 Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist,Color.red);
 Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist - new Vector3(0, 0, variation), Color.red);
 Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist + new Vector3(0, 0, variation), Color.red);

 if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward, out raycastHitFront, maxdist)) 
 {
     Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward*3, Color.green);
     print("Front Hit: " + raycastHitFront.transform.name);
 }

 if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist - new Vector3(0, 0, otklonenie), out raycastHitLeft, maxdist))
 {
     print("Left Hit: " + raycastHitLeft.transform.name);
 }

 if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist + new Vector3(0, 0, otklonenie), out raycastHitRight, maxdist))
 {
     Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward * maxdist + new Vector3(0, 0, otklonenie), Color.green);
     print("Right Hit: " + raycastHitRight.transform.name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну может потому что ты лучи кидаешь в сторону **transform.forward**, а этот вектор у объекта всегда направлен вдоль локальной оси **Z**, и если ты поворачиваешь, поворачивается и **forward**.